# Why use HTML and not HAML?

Tags: html, haml

In various forums and blogs, I see some people promoting [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) and some promoting HTML. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using HAML vs HTML?

I just want to understand what I'm missing out on if I use HAML in favor of HTML (if any).

Comment: I had to Google what HAML is, which kind of is an answer in itself. :) However I tend to vote to close as subjective and argumentative -  there are dozens of markup languages out there and discussing every one's advantages and disadvantages feels kind of pointless to me without some specific focus.

Comment: I like HAML, but I want to know if I will paint my self into a corner by using it. I'm not looking for what you feel about HTML vs HAML.

Answer (score 16):

You are trying to compare Apples to Oranges.  Browsers only understand HTML.  HAML is just a templating language that gets transformed into HTML (e.g. same final output).  If you find the HAML syntax to be easier than HTML then go for it.  However IMHO - abstracting away what actual elements you are generating just makes applying CSS and doing JavaScript navigation that much more difficult.

Personally if I wanted to "trim" my HTML, I would put content into tags (depends on your serverside technology)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
  <x:awesomeListThing data="$foo"/>

  <x:foreach data="$bar">
    <x:renderBazWidget/>
  </x:foreach>
  <div>random content that hasn't been "tagified" yet.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then inside any tag's template you'll be able to see the actual HTML structure that is being generated.

Comment: +1 for writing HTML when you want to write HTML. Although the XSLT-like syntax of your example did make me think twice ;o)

Comment: hehe yeah XSLT can be a bit overwhelming at first glance, but the idea with custom tags is to break down common "fragments" of code into *re-usable* components.  If done well, the view markup is very clean, and maintenance of the tags makes making global fixes/updates very easy.  Even if you don't use any if/else/foreach tags the individual "widgets" become much more maintainable.

Answer (score 6):

On Stackoverflow - HTML has 65k followers. You WILL get an answer, most likely many answers, in a very short amount of time. HAML has 157 followers. Simple math.

Answer (score 5):

The main disadvantage of using HAML over HTML is simply that HTML is just about universal among web developers, where as the HAML community is still a relatively small community. This would undoubtly make finding developers to work on your project in the future a more daunting task.

But if you have the resources, you could argue that to be an advantage. Ensuring you only hired developers that were capable and experience in HAML.

The other major down side I can see is that if you have graphics/web designers working on your templates, separate from your development team, they would also have to be familiar with HAML. As you can imagine there are very few graphics/web designers who capable of it, and few tools to help them.

Comment: pardon any poor spelling/grammar, it's late here

Answer (score 4):

Google `HAML`. I am sure, you will get relevant stuff to understand it.

Haml is:

- Easy to read and visually expresses your DOM hierarchy
- Easy to learn
- Ported to other languages
- Well-maintained and has a huge community
- Popular with designers because it borrows CSS syntax
- Almost as fast as plain ERB
- Makes many types of error impossible (or very difficult)

See here :

- [Your attitude to Haml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93540/your-attitude-to-haml)

Comment: I agree, but would note that HAML is more for Developers and you will find my Web Designer will prefer to use HTML.

Answer (score 2):

When major IDEs (such as Aptana) learn to parse HAML, we can return to the question. Right now I see HTML's superiority in that it's widely supported and understood by common parsers. You get proper syntax colouring and any errors or validation problems get marked instantly. This is not true of HAML.

Additionally, consider web templates. They're usually (X)HTML + CSS, be them ready templates for hire or the designs your designer cuts for you. What are your odds of getting a, say, HAML+SASS template instead of the usual XHTML+CSS?

HAML needs to gain more field and its community needs to grow much more before it's a viable alternative to HTML. Currently most web coders don't even know what HAML is, not to mention writing anything in HAML.